# How can i Remove binami corner banner on Ghost CMS

Tags: google-cloud-platform, ssh, google-compute-engine, bitnami, ghost-blog

I try'd many time using ssh to remove this banner but ssh alway show in bnconfig not found.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K5XEy.png)

Comment: I've installed Ghost Certified by Bitnami from Marketplace and found no issues with command `sudo /opt/bitnami/apps/ghost/bnconfig --disable_banner 1`. Please provide more details about your use case. Please do not use pictures to share commands and outputs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at the documentation [Remove The Bitnami Banner](https://docs.bitnami.com/google/how-to/bitnami-remove-banner/):

> **To remove the banner link to the Bitnami Info page**, follow these steps:
>
> - Log in to into your server console using SSH and execute the following command. Remember to replace APPNAME with the actual name or
>   directory location of your application.     `sudo /opt/bitnami/apps/APPNAME/bnconfig --disable_banner 1`
> - Restart the Web server.
>
>   - If you’re using Apache, execute the command below:
>
>     ```
>     sudo /opt/bitnami/ctlscript.sh restart apache
>     ```
>   - If you’re using NGINX, execute the command below:
>
>     ```
>     sudo /opt/bitnami/ctlscript.sh restart nginx
>     ```
>
> **NOTE**: The above steps will only remove the corner banner. The Bitnami Info page will still be available by visiting
> http://DOMAIN/bitnami/index.html.

I've installed **Ghost Certified by Bitnami** from GCP Marketplace and found no issues with command `sudo /opt/bitnami/apps/ghost/bnconfig --disable_banner 1`.

If you're still facing this issue, you can try to reinstall Ghost CMS from the Marketplace or/and reach [Bitnami Community](https://community.bitnami.com/).